# Volume Property has no effect when sending apns payload using FCM for critical alerts

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I'm using FCM to send critical alerts for my application but I'm trying to adjust the volume as the critical alerts function uses max volume by default. I've seen a few examples of using the volume property but it has no effect when sending payloads. Is there an alternative way to use a set volume without modifying all the sound files directly?

Here is the format of my payload:

```
apns: {
          payload: {
            aps: {
              'interruption-level': 'critical',
              sound: user.sound,
              volume: 0.3,
              critical: 1,
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely up to speed with critical alerts being integrated with FCM. However, I have heard that sometimes the volume adjustment only works with default apple sound dictionary.

I have been trying to use this block to send critical alerts, however, the notification won't even send, period. Pretty sure the critical alerts payload is correct for the most part, including the sound. Might be a good debugging starting spot.

```
apns: data.isCritical ? {
      payload: {
        aps: {
          alert: data.body,
          sound: {
            critical: true,
            name: 'default',
            volume: 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    }
```